# Understanding output_attentions

Tags: nlp, huggingface-transformers, bert-language-model

I have a question about `output_attentions`, and I need to make a heatmap about the attention of the final layer of the BERT model. But I do not know if the `output_attentions[0]` is the first or last layer. I tried to check the documentation, but I did not find it.

Answer (score 0):

`output_attentions[0]` are the attention scores of the first attention layer. You can also verify this with the following code:

```py
import torch
from transformers import BertModel, BertTokenizerFast

model_id = 'bert-base-uncased'

t = BertTokenizerFast.from_pretrained(model_id)
m = BertModel.from_pretrained(model_id)

model_input = t("this is a test", return_tensors="pt")

with torch.inference_mode():
  output = m(**model_input, output_attentions=True)

  print(len(output.attentions))
  
  # Tokenembeddings
  outputEmbeddings = m.embeddings(model_input.input_ids)

  #the first tensor is the attention of the first encoding layer
  print(torch.equal(output.attentions[0], m.encoder.layer[0](outputEmbeddings,output_attentions=True)[1]))

  previousLayer = outputEmbeddings
  for x in range(12):
      previousLayer, attention = m.encoder.layer[x](previousLayer,output_attentions=True)
      print(torch.equal(output.attentions[x], attention))
```

Output:

```
12
True
True
True
True
True
True
True
True
True
True
True
True
True
```